# positive definite matrix with a trivial kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If a kernel of a matrix $A \in M_n$ is a trivial subspace, which means that it contains only $0$ vector, then the matrix $A^TA$ is positive definite.

How can I give an answer to this without any calculations? I am first supposed to say if it's true or not, then give an explanation why..

Comment: And your thoughts and partial reasoning on this are ???

Answer (score 3):

Without any assumption, ${}^\intercal AA$ is symmetric positive.

Now, let $X$ be a column vector, then: $$\langle{}^\intercal AAX,X\rangle=\|AX\|^2\geqslant 0.$$
Whence the definite property, if $\ker(A)=\{0\}$.

*Reminder.* For all vectors $X$ and $Y$, $\langle X,Y\rangle={}^\intercal XY$.